# UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal: how to change order from top-bottom to left-right

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm realizing a collection view with flow layout. The user can toggle between horizontal and vertical scroll direction.

Anyhow:
when it deals with horizontal direction, the elements within the table view are positioned from top to bottom, something like this:

**1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9**

Nevertheless, I want to change the order from left to right, namely:

**1  2 3

4  5 6

7  8 9**

My researches didn't bring the desired result - in addition, the APIs of collection view and flow layout don't offer a flag which enables the user to flip columns and rows.

Has anybody found a solution to it?
I'm wondering that apparently such problem hasn't been discussed yet.
In addition, the most humans read from left to right and not from top to bottom - so why doesn't Apple offer an option to change the behavior of the cell positioning?

By the way, I want to keep the number of rows constant ...

Answer (score 0):

Cheeky as I'm by nature, I could figure out by myself how to do (yes, this saved my day):

First of all, I subclass **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** (name of my subclass is CollectionViewFlowLayout).

Then I overwrite the method ***prepareLayout***, where I initialize a cache (mutable array with UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) with ALL elements, which I get from the collection view -> so lost elements due to scrolling is no more an issue!

At last I overwrite ***layoutAttributesForElementsInRect*** where I extract all UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes again, overwriting the geometrical position (=frame) of each element in the cache. As I get all elements from the cache (array), contrary to

```
 NSMutableArray * attributesArray = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: rect] mutableCopy];
```

I can process all cells - not only the visible ones!

The caching has an additional benefit: elements must be updated only after layout invalidation - thus scrolling is much smoother, without flickering.

Here's my source code:

```
@interface CollectionViewFlowLayout() {
    // cache for all collection view cell's layouts
    NSMutableArray * cache;
    // flag indicating that attributes can be read from cache (performance issue)
    bool attributesHaveBeenUpdated;

    // number of all cells in the collection view
    int numberOfTotalCells;
}
@end

@implementation CollectionViewFlowLayout

/**
 *
 *  Is called whenever the collection view’s layout is invalidated,
 *  for example after device rotation
 *
 **/
- (void)prepareLayout {

    attributesHaveBeenUpdated = false;

    if (!cache) {
        cache = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

    if (cache.count == 0) {

        numberOfTotalCells = (int)[self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]; //(int) attributesArray.count; //

        // now populate the cache with ALL cells of collection view (not only the visibe ones)
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfTotalCells; i++) {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * attributes = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
            [cache addObject:attributes];
        }
    }
}


/**
 *
 *  Is called whenever cells appear/disappear after scrolling
 *  and after "prepareLayout"
 *
 **/
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    NSMutableArray * attributesArray = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: rect] mutableCopy]; // reflects only the attributes of visible cells within the scroll area!

    if (self.scrollDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical || !cache) {
        return attributesArray; // nothing to do ... the order of the elements is ok
    }

    if (attributesHaveBeenUpdated) {
        // nothing to do, just take the elements from cache!
        return cache;
    }


    // height of collection view
    float availableHeight = self.collectionViewContentSize.height;
    // height of a single collection view cell (here: equal sizes!)
    float cellHeight = ((UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)attributesArray[0]).frame.size.height;
    // height of a single collection view cell (here: equal sizes!)
    float cellWidth = ((UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)attributesArray[0]).frame.size.width;
    // minimal spacing between two rows -> to be multiplied later with (numberOfRows - 1)
    float minLineSpacing = self.minimumLineSpacing;
    // minimal spacing between two columns
    float minInteritemSpacing = self.minimumInteritemSpacing;

    // now calculate the maximal number of rows in function of cellHeight,
    // minLineSpacing and availableHeight -> formula comes from:
    // availableHeight = numberOfRows*cellHeight + (numberOfRows-1)*minLineSpacing
    int numberOfRows = floor((availableHeight + minLineSpacing) / (cellHeight + minLineSpacing));


    /**
     *
     * Now we need to calculate the new positioning of the cells in function of
     * the maximal number of possible rows (=numberOfRows). We start with the
     * first row and try to achieve the best reapartition of cells in each row,
     * so that rows 1...N-1 are filled with the same number of cells (=n). The last
     * row should be filled with the remaining elements -> number = between 1 and n.
     *
     **/
    // get the number of cells until the penultimate row
    int numberOfCellsPerMainRow = ceil((float)numberOfTotalCells / (float)numberOfRows);

    // number of total cells from row 1...N-1
    int numberOfMainRowCells = numberOfCellsPerMainRow*(numberOfRows-1);
    // number of cells in last row
    int numberOfLastRowCells = numberOfTotalCells - numberOfMainRowCells;

    // special case : if no remaining element for last row, decrease the number of cells
    // in previous rows -> remember: we want to fill each available row!
    if (numberOfLastRowCells == 0) {
        numberOfCellsPerMainRow--;
        numberOfMainRowCells = numberOfCellsPerMainRow*(numberOfRows-1);
        numberOfLastRowCells += numberOfRows;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<numberOfTotalCells; i++) {

        // now overwrite the geometrical properties of each cell
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attr = cache[i];// get from cache ...

        int row = floor((float)i/(float)numberOfCellsPerMainRow);
        int col = i % numberOfCellsPerMainRow;

        // overwrite layout in the cache ("call by reference")
        attr.frame = CGRectMake(col*(cellWidth+minInteritemSpacing), row*(cellHeight+minLineSpacing), cellWidth, cellHeight);
    }

    attributesHaveBeenUpdated = true; // the next time, read from cache!

    return cache;
}

// always return YES
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This approach works well - there is only one small issue:
when I scroll to right, the last elements are cut off - thus only partially displayed. Maybe the collection view content size is still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the above-mentioned scroll issue, I found the following solution:

1. Calculating the maximal width of a row (in ***layoutAttributesForElementsInRect***),
2. Overriding ***collectionViewContentSize*** in the subclass of **UICollectionViewFlowLayout**.

```
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
        return CGSizeMake(maxRowWidth, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
}
```

and in ***layoutAttributesForElementsInRect*** (see above)

```
// get the width of the largest row (we need it for increasing the scroll area)
maxRowWidth = numberOfCellsPerMainRow * cellWidth + (numberOfCellsPerMainRow - 1) * minInteritemSpacing;
```

All works fine now!

[Here's a GIF of my final collection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM7oq.gif)